# Как выровнять элементы следующим способом

Tags: html, css

Скачал себе шаблон, чтобы поучиться верстке, но столкнулся с такой проблемой не могу выровнять элементы следующим образом [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
   

     .doc {
     padding-top: 170px;
     margin-bottom: 110px;
     text-align: center;
     
    }
    
    .doc p {
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #a1a1a1;
    }
    
    .block {
     margin-left: 70px;
    }
    
    .block img {
     display: block;
    }
    
     .block {
     display: inline-flex;
    
    }
```

```html
   

     <section class="documents__photos">
      <div class="doc">
       <div class="block">
        <img src="img/Documents.png" alt="">
         <h2>Documents</h2>
         <p>
          This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem <br> Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor <br> aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin
         </p>
       </div>
    
       <div class="block">
        <img src="img/Camera.png" alt="">
         <h2>Photos</h2>
         <p>
          This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem <br> Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor <br> aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin
         </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: Приведите в порядок код

Comment: подредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотреть на всю страницу

```css
.doc {
  padding-top: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.doc p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #a1a1a1;
}

.block {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.block img {
  display: block;
}

.doc,
.block {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="documents__photos">
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="block">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x220" alt="">
      <div>
        <h2>Documents</h2>
        <p>
          This is Photoshop's version of Lorem <br> Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor <br> aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x220" alt="">
      <div>
        <h2>Photos</h2>
        <p>
          This is Photoshop's version of Lorem <br> Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor <br> aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin
        </p>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. тоже нашел решение, похожее на ваше, только с созданием доп блоков)